# Tratamiento de mini diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente programa el cual toma como parámetros un diccionario claves (str) y valores (int) y dos números enteros. El programa devuelve un nuevo diccionario conteniendo las parejas del diccionario pasado como primer parámetro cuyos valores se encuentren en el rango comprendido entre el segundo y tercer parámetro (ambos incluidos).

El problema que tengo es que no sé como establecer el rango para que escoja ambos elementos incluidos

```
OUTPUT: {'b': 4}
OUTPUT ESPERADO : {'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 8, 'f': 10,'}
```

```
dicc = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 8, 'e': 3,
    'f': 10,'g':  12, 'h': 13, 'i': 14, 'j': 15
}
inicio = 4
fin = 10
def funcion(dicc, inicio, fin):
  diccionariovacio = {}
  for clave, valor in dicc.items():
      if clave and valor in range(start, end + 1):
          diccionariovacio[clave] = valor
          return diccionariovacio
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Tras corregir el error indicado por lucasgonzalez, sigue sin funcionar correctamente.  En este caso, el problema es que tengo dos pequeños errores en la ejecución del problema. El primer error es que la clave `{'': 10}` no se muestra y el segundo error es que no se muestra la clave `{0: 179}`

```
OUTPUT1: {'XYZ': 1, 'ERD': 4, 'WSX': 7, 'GDF': 8, 'ERS': 3, 'WSD': 12, 'UHB': 13, 'YGH': 14, 'QWR': 15}

OUTPUT ESPERADO1 : {'XYZ': 1, 'ERD': 4, 'WSX': 7, 'GDF': 8, 'ERS': 3, '': 10, 'WSD': 12, 'UHB': 13, 'YGH': 14, 'QWR': 15}

OUTPUT2:{1: -392, 2: -135, 3: -134, 6: -615, 7: 29, 9: 20}

OUTPUT ESPERADO2:{0: -179, 1: -392, 2: -135, 3: -134, 6: -615, 7: 29, 9: 20}
```

Comment: En efecto he editado la pregunta para no formular una nueva, dado que cuando ejecuto el programa para dichos casos mencionado anteriormente me retorna un resultado inesperado

Comment: Si es necesario, edito nuevamente la pregunta en disposicion de como tenia yo el codigo inicialmente. Puse el código ya corregido para mostrar que el nuevo error que me surge no tiene que ver con el nivel de identacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparte del error que tenías con el `return` y que @lucasgonzalez ya ha corregido, respecto a tu nueva duda, el error está en esta línea:

```
if clave and valor in range(start, end + 1):
```

Dejando de lado que has puesto aquí `start, end`, variables que no están definidas, y asumiendo que querías decir `inicio, fin`, el error está en que has escrito `if clave and valor` ¿qué pinta la clave aquí? ¿no se trataba sólo de mirar si el valor estaba o no en el rango dado? Deberías haber hecho esto:

```
if valor in range(inicio, fin+1):
```

y con esto ya tu programa ya funciona.

## Bonus

Esto tiene pinta de ser un ejercicio de clase, y seguramente tu profesor no vea bien que hayas usado `in range()` para resolverlo. De hecho, ha sido un poco por casualidad que ha funcionado ya que `range()` no sirve para esto, sino para generar iteradores con números correlativos. El hecho de que implemente también el operador  `in` ha sido una feliz coincidencia (que yo no conocía, por cierto).

La forma más habitual de saber si un `valor` está comprendido entre dos números dados sería esta:

```
if inicio <= valor <= fin:
```

## Bonus 2

¿Cómo es que el código que tenías inicialmente llegaba a funcionar "medio bien" a pesar de haber metido `clave` en la condición? Por no dejar misterios sin explicar, esta es la razón:

Tu expresión equivale a esta otra, puesto que `and` tiene la menor precedencia de todas en cuanto al orden en que se hacen las operaciones:

```
if clave and (valor in range(inicio, fin + 1)):
```

por tanto se mira primero si `valor` está en el rango. El resultado de mirar eso puede salir `False` o `True`. Supongamos que sale `True`, como era el caso del 10 o del -179. Ya que esa segunda parte sale `True`, la expresión que seguidamente Python tiene que evaluar es:

```
if clave and True:
```

En caso de que `clave` sea una cadena, su valor "booleano" equivale siempre a `True`, excepto para las cadenas vacías, que equivalen a `False`. Por eso cuando la clave era una cadena vacía, esta expresión salía `False` a pesar de que el número estuviera en el rango, y el elemento no se guardaba.

En caso de que `clave` sea un entero, su valor "booleano" equivale siempre a `True`, excepto para el cero que equivale a  `False`. Por eso cuando la clave era cero, esta expresión salía `False` a pesar de que el número estuviera en el rango.

Por esta razón tu algoritmo funcionaba "casi bien". En los casos en las claves eran distintas de `''` o de `0`, tu expresión se comportaba igual que la debías haber usado en la que `clave` no aparecía. Pero en los casos en que la clave era una cadena vacía o cero, entonces salía `False` independientemente de que el valor estuviera o no en el rango.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El codigo estas bien, el problema es que estas dando `return`, por lo que tu codigo devuelve ese diccionario en la primer ocurrencia.

Hasta el if que comprueba el valor esta perfecto, pero ahi no debes retornar el diccionario porque en la primera vez que se cumple la condicion ejecuta el return y termina la funcion. El `return` deberias hacerlo fuera del `for`

```
def funcion(dicc, inicio, fin):
  diccionariovacio = {}
  for clave, valor in dicc.items():
      if clave and valor in range(start, end + 1):
          diccionariovacio[clave] = valor
  return diccionariovacio
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda